# Using customer attribute in conditions Catalog Price Rules

Tags: catalog-price-rules, customer-attribute

Is it possible to add a customer attribute to the list with conditions under “please choose a condition to add” under “Catalog Price Rules”

It says “product attributes” but I also see Gender in that list which is a customer attribute.

I would like use an attribute with the company code, so I can give an individual discount to (customers of a) company.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? Also looking to add catalog or cart price rules based for individual customer accounts, not whole customer groups.

Comment: I now use [XLS Pricecalculator by Moonsoft][1]
All you need to do is upload all prices, calculations, whatever in an Excel spreadsheet. So easy. So fast.

And customer support is very helpful.
This should be a standard function in Magento.

Check it out and see it it fits your needs
.

  [1]: https://www.moonsoft.es/component/hikashop/product/37-XLSPrice%20Calculator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Gender` is a product attribute, so that's why it shows up.
Products for men, woman or both.

You should go with customer groups, add the customer in the correct customer group and set the price rules accordantly. Or customer specific prices for your products.

Comment: Oh, yes, of course, also a product attribute, I do not use that, so had not thought of that.
But next to the customer groups with their discounts,  I also have individual customers (employees of a company)  that get a discount on top of that… They have a profile_ID as attribute. 
As Magento does not allow customers to be in two different groups, so I am looking for a way around.
But thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Hi it's happend long time but is there a way a spesific customer set a catalog_rule ?
customer group = 469 has % 10 percent in catalog rule.
but i need add the discount just customerid = 101 has %12 percent in catalog rule for 2 month also without change any group.